# Почему все подряд не используют critical css?

Tags: html, css

Прочитал статью про critical css. Смысл в том чтобы вставлять инлайн стили для первого видимого экрана сайта при загрузке. Но как-то не особо заметил чтобы все сайты поголовно это использовали. Возможно это не так нужно(полезно)?

Comment: [What's so bad about in-line CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css)

Comment: @Grundy Инлайн стили имелось ввиду объявляемые в тэге style. И ведьм мы не все стили выносим, а только для отображения первого экрана сайта.

Answer (score 3):

Помимо всего, что вы написали critical css влияет на оптимизацию.

## До использования critical css

[image: Before]

## После использования critical css

[image: After]

[Источник + Подробное описание тут](https://github.com/addyosmani/critical-path-css-demo)

Comment: Я понимаю зачем придуман этот подход. Вопрос в том почему его не использует большинство сайтов.

Comment: Может незнают о нем? Я сам недавно узнал например) да и может быть используют аналогичные средства для данной задачи